# C# Threadpool creating UI Element

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, threadpool

I am updating a listbox via databind and one of the columns I am trying to insert is a checkbox.    This update is being processed by a threadpool and I am able to insert the data fine, except for the checkbox.  When I create the checkbox its displaying the xaml instead of the checkbox element.
i.e.

> System.Windows.Controls.Checkbox Content: IsChecked:False

Definition of `NotesReminderViewDetails`

```
private struct NotesRemindersViewDetails
{
    public string NoteReminderID { get; set; }
    public string NoteReminderEnterDate { get; set; }
    public string NoteReminderDueDate { get; set; }
    public string NoteReminderConents { get; set; }
    public CheckBox NoteReminderCompleted { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the code I am using to update the listview. `NoteReminderType` is a struct with all the note/reminder information.

```
NoteReminderType noteType = noteReminder.NoteReminderDetails;

NotesRemindersViewDetails noteReminderDetails = new NotesRemindersViewDetails();
noteReminderDetails.NoteReminderID = noteType.UserFriendlyNoteReminderID.ToString();
noteReminderDetails.NoteReminderEnterDate = noteType.InsertionDate.ToShortDateString();
noteReminderDetails.NoteReminderDueDate = noteType.DueDate.ToShortDateString();
noteReminderDetails.NoteReminderConents = noteType.Description;

listViewNotesReminders.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, new Action(delegate()
{
    noteReminderDetails.NoteReminderCompleted = new CheckBox();

    listViewNotesReminders.Items.Add(noteReminderDetails);
}));
```

What do I need to change to get the checkbox to be displayed instead of the xaml form the threadpool thread?

**EDIT**
Here is the xaml code for the listview

```
<ListView.View>
    <GridView>
        <GridViewColumn Header="ID" Width="20" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=NoteReminderID}" />
        <GridViewColumn Header="Entered Date" Width="Auto" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=NoteReminderEnterDate}" />
        <GridViewColumn Header="Due Date" Width="75" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=NoteReminderDueDate}" />
        <GridViewColumn Header="Note Contents" Width="300" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=NoteReminderConents}" />
        <GridViewColumn Header="Completed" Width="Auto" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=NoteReminderCompleted}" />
    </GridView>
</ListView.View>
```

Comment: Is there any specific reason to use CheckBox, instead of "bool" field?

Comment: I want the user to be able to change the status of the note/reminder by checking the checkbox to mark it as completed.

Comment: You are mixing data and presentation my having a control in `NotesRemindersViewDetails`. Also it is far more usual to use a class rather than a struct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rather than putting a UI element (`CheckBox`) in the data for the `ListView`, you should define a template so you can render the column as a checkbox, and just use a `Boolean` for the data.  Using a `CheckBox` in your data is mixing your UI and data layers.

**Update:**

Here's an example (not tested) of how to make a custom column template:

```
<ListView.View>
    <GridView>
        <GridViewColumn Header="ID" Width="20" 
                        DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=NoteReminderID}" />
        <GridViewColumn Header="Entered Date" Width="Auto" 
                        DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=NoteReminderEnterDate}" />
        <GridViewColumn Header="Due Date" Width="75" 
                        DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=NoteReminderDueDate}" />
        <GridViewColumn Header="Note Contents" Width="300" 
                        DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=NoteReminderConents}" />
        <GridViewColumn Header="Completed" Width="Auto">
            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=NoteReminderCompleted}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        </GridViewColumn>
    </GridView>
</ListView.View>
```

Comment: How can I go about doing something like this?  I am still learning WPF and its ins and outs.  Or if you can point me to a good tutorial for WPF templates.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use bool field for NoteReminderCompleted instead of CheckBox.